# Android Dev - Text based game within an app

Tags: android

I am looking to add a simple text based trivia type game within an app I already have built for a Business. We would like to get more user interaction in the app. Further, I would like to have high scores...etc display in the app.

Creating a web serice and MySQL database would be simply enough to capture scores and query to top score. However, Is there soemthing like a free game API or something that would make this a lot easier than creating a game from scratch? I have seen some really complex game api's, but I am not trying to make an entire app. Just add a simple trivia game inside my app.

Any suggestions? Comments?

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radical Breeze's [Illumination Software Creator](http://radicalbreeze.com/) has a [tutorial on building a text-based game](http://www.radicalbreeze.com/tutorials/ISC-Tutorial-BuildAChooseYourOwnAdventureGame.pdf) with their program.  Illumination  is a visual development environment like App Inventor.

If you don't want to go through the tutorial, I believe you can just download the code for the game.  The program comes in a free download version.  Illumination generates full source code for a number of platforms, including Android, though I think you may have to pay for mobile platform code generation.  (Payment is "choose your own price".)

All generated code is "native".  I.e., no special API.